# How to highlight parent table row based on table header attribute

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color for the entire table row (using CSS) when the table header has an attribute of commit="123".  I've tried this:

```
[commit="123"] {
  color:#aaffff;
  background-color:#111111;
}
```

However, this only changes the table header (1).  How can I select the entire table row (1 entry 1) in which the table header has commit set to "123"?  Thanks!

```css
[commit="123"] {
  color: #aaffff;
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<table class="code">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="1" commit="123">1</th>
      <td>
        <i>entry 1</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="2" commit="456">2</th>
      <td>
        <i>entry 2</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just apply the `commit` to the table rows instead of the table header? Unfortunately CSS does not currently support reverse selectors for parents.

```css
[commit="123"] {
  color: #aaffff;
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<table class="code">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1" commit="123">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>
        <i>entry 1</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" commit="456">
      <th>2</th>
      <td>
        <i>entry 2</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [general sibling combinator (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to select all following `td`s in the row.

This won't style the `tr`, there is no CSS selector that can do as you wish, but you could achieve a similar effect in this way.

```css
[commit="123"],
[commit="123"]~td {
  color: #aaffff;
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<table class="code">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="1" commit="123">1</th>
      <td>
        <i>entry 1</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i>entry 1.2</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="2" commit="456">2</th>
      <td>
        <i>entry 2</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i>entry 2.2</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding **commit**  to table headers (i.e.) **th** you need to write it in  to achieve your requirement.

Hope this helps.